# Finding an integral basis for a lattice defined in terms of an equation modulo p

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

Let p be a prime number, u relatively prime to p, and $\Lambda := \lbrace (a, b) \in \mathbb{Z}^2 : b \equiv au$ (mod p)$\rbrace$. How then can I find an integral basis $v_1, v_2$ for $\Lambda$?

I need to find this in order to compute the covolume, which is supposed to be the determinant of an integral basis, but it's not clear to me how to get a basis out of this sort of definition for the lattice. I'd like an answer that I could extrapolate out to other lattices defined in terms of equations modulo p, if possible.

(Also, I'm uncertain about the tags here; algebraic number theory is where this problem has come up, but I don't know if it strictly belongs to that field or to some other)

Comment: Your $\Lambda$ does not appear to be a lattice.  For instance, if $p=3$, consider the pairs $(1,1)$ and $(2,1)$.  Then both are in $\Lambda$, since you may use $u=1$ for the first pair and $u=2$ for the second.  But $(1,1) + (2,1) = (3,2)$ is not in $\Lambda$, since there is no $u$ such that $3u \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$.

Comment: Hm...it looks like I've misread my source material on what u is supposed to be. Sorry about that, editing now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An integral basis is $(1,u)$ and $(0,p)$.

The lattice generated by these vectors contains $(p,0) = p \cdot (1,u) - u \cdot(0,p)$, so clearly contains $p\mathbb{Z} \times p\mathbb{Z}$.  If $(a,b)$ is in $\Lambda$ with $p \nmid a$, then let $c$ be an integer with $ac \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.  Then $(a,b) = a \cdot (1,cb) + r \cdot (0,p)$ for some integer $r$.  Furthermore, $(1,cb) \in \Lambda$, since $ua \equiv b \pmod{p}$ implies $u \equiv cb \pmod{p}$.  Thus, $(a,b)$ is in the sublattice generated by $(1,u)$ and $(0,p)$, which is therefore the whole lattice.